# Elasticsearch "search query term" returns 0 hints for nested object keys in _doc type index

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am having a problem searching in elasticsearch. Whenever I try to search by term like the curl below, I get the result that I want.

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/XXXXXX/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "time": {
                "value": "2021-02-09T00:09:49.457Z",
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Example of response. The type says _doc so a nested query should work the same way.

```json
{"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "XXXX",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "xxxxx",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": { ... }
]}
```

However when I try to search for a nested key, I get 0 hits in the response.

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/XXXXXX/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "code.type": {
                "value": "animals",
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: It would be useful to see the index-mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the documents you try to search for it exist make sure about your index mapping about your fields and if the "code" field is keyword search with "code.keyword" and remove the "boost" field if it didn't work again change your query syntax and strategy such as leaf queries

```
curl -XGET "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/XXXXXX/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "query": {"match": {    "code.type": "animals"  }}}'
```

And if your field is keyword

```
    curl -XGET "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/XXXXXX/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "query": {"match": {    "code.type": "animals"  }}}'
```

Feel free to update the conversation and comment .